# How can I install a Windows 10 KVM VM on a ZVOL: pick the correct virtio drivers

Tags: drivers, windows, kvm, zfs, virtio

I was trying to install windows 10 on an NTFS formatted zvol, but I kept getting BSODs:

```
user@ubuntu:~$ virt-install \
> --name myWINVM1 \
> --ram 4096 \
> --disk path=/guest_images2/myWINVM1.img,bus=virtio,size=120 \
> --vcpus 4 \
> --os-type windows \
> --os-variant win10 \
> --network bridge=virbr0 \
> --graphics vnc \
> --console pty,target_type=serial \
> --disk /home/user/Downloads/Win10_Edu_1803_English_x64.iso,device=cdrom,bus=ide \
> --disk /home/user/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1.141.iso,device=cdrom,bus=ide

Starting install...
Allocating 'myWINVM1.img'                           | 120 GB  00:00     
Domain creation completed.
Restarting guest.
```

[image: The BSOD]

Attempting to follow the advice here https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1593190, I created /etc/modprobe.d/kvm.conf with the line:
options kvm ignore_msrs=1
which changed nothing

and also manually setting the cpu type to Opteron_G5 (as suggested in the above thread) which also did not work

```
user@ubuntu:~$ virt-install \
> --name myWINVM1 \
> --ram 4096 \
> --disk path=/guest_images2/myWINVM1.img,bus=virtio,size=120 \
> --vcpus 4 \
> --cpu Opteron_G5 \
> --os-type windows \
> --os-variant win10 \
> --network bridge=virbr0 \
> --graphics vnc \
> --console pty,target_type=serial \
> --disk /home/user/Downloads/Win10_Edu_1803_English_x64.iso,device=cdrom,bus=ide \
> --disk /home/user/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1.141.iso,device=cdrom,bus=ide

Starting install...
Allocating 'myWINVM1.img'                           | 120 GB  00:00     
ERROR    the CPU is incompatible with host CPU: Host CPU does not provide required features: xop, fma4, tbm
Removing disk 'myWINVM1.img'                        |    0 B  00:00     
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start myWINVM1
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

I then set the CPU to core2duo, which got me a bit further, to the part where I choose which drive to install on, but nothing was available. I was prompted to install a cd with the drivers, I thought that must be the virtio ISO, but I windows complained about them being unsigned.

```
virt-install \
--name myWINVM1 \
--ram 4096 \
--disk path=/guest_images2/myWINVM1.img,bus=virtio,size=120 \
--vcpus 4 \
--cpu core2duo \
--os-type windows \
--os-variant win10 \
--network bridge=virbr0 \
--graphics vnc \
--console pty,target_type=serial \
--disk /home/james/Downloads/Win10_Edu_1803_English_x64.iso,device=cdrom,bus=ide \
--disk /home/james/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1.141.iso,device=cdrom,bus=ide
```

[image: No drives!]

[image: And it doesnt like my drivers ISO. Is lack of drivers even the problem?]
About my system:
Host: Ubuntu Server 18.04 with XFCE4 as a GUI
Motherboard: X399 Taichi
CPU: Threadripper 1950x

So I guess this leaves me with three questions:

1. What else can I try to get past the boot screen other than lying about what CPU I am using?
2. Does my inability to see my ZVOL have to do with my virtio ISO or my virt-install options?
3. Is it expected that Windows wont accept the drivers on the virtio ISO at this stage?

EDITS: additional things I tried
I unchecked "Hide drivers that aren't compatible with this computer's hardware" and navigated to what I believe to be the right driver, and I did find the driver, but still no drives.
E:\vioscsi\2k16\amd64\
[image: The drivers I tried to use]

So I guess now my question is whether I picked the right drivers and if so, what else should I try?

Comment: Should I have posted this in Serverfault? Mods feel free to move it if you think it's a better fit there.

Answer (score 1):

I was picking the wrong drivers. This thread pointed me to the right ones (except I selected win10): https://askubuntu.com/questions/673957/how-do-you-install-the-virtio-hdd-drivers-for-kvm-on-windows-7

Where is this documented? None of the official documentation I looked at said anything about how to know which drivers are which.

[image: The right drivers]

[image: Success!]

[image: More success!]

And of course to get past the BSOD, I had to set --cpu core2duo, which kind of bothers me. Can I expect that to cause performance problems?

Other --cpu settings I tried and the results:
 core2duo - worked
 kvm64 - froze at windows boot screen
 qemu64 - worked
 threadripper - unknown CPU model
 EPYC - BSOD

Comment: The core2duo thing is (I think) fixed in the 1809 release. As for performance, you'll do better with virtio-scsi instead of the virtio-blk that that tutorial advises.